# Triggering job on github pr to a specific branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using the github branch source plugin: `https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-branch-source-plugin` to trigger jobs from github pr.

I would like jenkins trigger a build only when a pr to the master branch is made. I tried to use the branch filter plugin but it doesn't trigger at any pr. I guess it doesnt work on prs, only on direct push to branches.

is that possible?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438523/github-branch-source-plugin-only-scan-for-pull-requests) out.

Comment: @Samarth I need this solution only for a PR for one specific branch. thats the problem

Comment: Just in case you know the PR number, you can use `Filter by name (with wildcards)` behaviour and add your PR number in the `Include` section like `PR-12`.

Answer (score 1):

this should to the trick. (there is a downside though as this condition is not on a plugin level, so the build will be triggered on other events too)

```
stage('build') {
  when {
    allOf {
      branch 'PR-*'
      environment name: 'CHANGE_TARGET', value: 'master'
    }
  }
  steps {
    sh 'building pr on master'
  }
}
```